# input tag not working properly with Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I was trying to implement a feature in angular 5 and encountered a problem that input tag isn't working properly.

Here's the link to the code : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-tutorial-eiacpx)

It would be awesome if someone could tell me if there's something I have done wrong here, or is it just some angular version issue. Because the same code is working fine with angular 10.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry Diksha my answer can help you with the angular 6+. I have removed it. I will try to find a solution.

Comment: @StPaulis I have an object and have to display data in such format. Here I used some dummy data, And similarly, I have to display input tags and take the user inputs, but if you see the input tags you won't be able to give input there.

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan okay. No problem.

Comment: @DikshaGoyal here is my answer, maybe this can help you find another workaround before find a solution: The problem is that your keyvalue pipe every time returns a new reference of the array, so angular every time will re-render all of the ngFor items. You can fix this by adding trackBy on your ngFor. It will check before re-rendering the item. and will only render the items which need re-rendering.

Comment: the problem is that `trackBy` comes on an angular 6+ version.

Comment: Then @DikshaGoyal probably should update :)

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan is there any substitute for the keyvalue pipe I have used here?

Comment: @DikshaGoyal I recommend you do the same in the ts file and after, loop over on normal array. I can show a simple example. If you have the same logic in multiple places you can define the static method of the helper class and use it everywhere where you need it.

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan sorry didn't get you. can you please share an example for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `keyvalue` pipe every time returns a new reference of the array, so angular every time will re-render all of the `ngFor` items. You can fix this by adding `trackBy` on your `ngFor`. It will check before re-rendering the item. and will only render the items which need re-rendering.

**Here is the working example:**

**Note:** there is one workaround example for the angular less than 6 and solution for the angular 6+

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-tutorial-p4uywe?file=app%2Fapp.component.html